# Apply StyleSheet to Textile with Redcloth?

Tags: ruby, stylesheet, redcloth

How do you apply an external stylesheet to a textile document with Ruby's Redcloth, so that I can convert it to HTML and it will apply the styles?

I understand how to apply styles individually to parts of text, but how to I define a whole style (say text with font-size 20, color red, alignment x, font-family y, etc.), and apply it to all the h2 tags, without having to copy-paste that {hash} everywhere?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why don't you use an external CSS stylesheet file and include it on your HTML template?

Answer (score 0):

If you have a html template where the RedCloth'd document is rendered, an external CSS should do the job.